# How to edit HTML source in DevTools

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools

I go to the sources tab and try to edit HTML file - I can't

whereas I can edit js/css files - curious, how can I edit the HTML? if I can only edit it via the Elements tab, then what can I do so those changes reflect in the HTML file found in sources? reason I ask is because I want to save the html file with all the different changes I've made using Devtools

Answer (score 0):

It's weird, but I do it by changing whatever I want in the elements-tab, then right click on the `<html>` tag and press `Copy as HTML`, then make a new .txt file, paste it in there, and rename it to a .html file!

Comment: Ya that's what I do as well but assuming there is a way to automate this